# Select NSTableViewCell via Bindings (without tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:)

Tags: objective-c, binding, nstableview, nstablecellview

Can I use bindings to magically select the type of NSTableCellView that I want?

I've successfully transitioned from cell-based to view-based NSTableViews. Now I want to transition from using delegate methods to bindings.

Using delegate I implement `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row` in order to return one of three NSTableCellViews that I want to use (depending on the type of data). I set `objectValue` and the NSTableCellViews use that for displaying data.

Even now, with bindings, I *can* use the same delegate method to return one of the views; I simply don't set `objectValue`, and the I get `objectValue` from bindings. It works.

I switched to bindings as a learning experience, but also to get rid of this code. Maybe `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row` is specifically a delegate method instead of datasource method because this is still the expected way to select the correct view?

Is there a better (or rather, bindings-only) way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach is to make one compound view that combines your three separate ones. You can basically embed your existing views into a tab view that doesn't show its tabs. Then, you can bind the tab view's `selectedIndex` or `selectedIdentifier` binding to a key path going through `objectValue` to pick which one to display.

Comment: That's the exact type of novel response I was hoping for, and it did the trick. Thanks!